# Is there a Firefox plugin that will allow me to edit the address in a popup?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, popups, address-bar

The website I'm developing uses a lot of popups. It is handy for me to be able to edit the address in the address bar so that I can append variables and such. FF seems to prevent me from doing this. Is there a plugin that will unlock it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [answer from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392271/635008) says popup windows with non-editable URLs is intended behavior to prevent spoofing.

It refers to the [mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=470051#c1) about it.

Comment: What's spoofing in this context?

Answer (score 7):

you can write the following on firebug console:

```
document.location="http://yoursite.com";
```

Then click Run

this will redirect the popup to the new location.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without a plugin.

Type `about:config` into Firefox's address bar, and press "Enter." Click the "I'll Be Careful, I Promise" button. Scroll down to the

```
dom.disable_window_open_feature.location
```

setting; then click anywhere within the setting's row to change its value to **True**. Pop-up windows will not be able to deactivate your address bar again.

```
dom.disable_window_open_feature.resizable
dom.disable_window_open_feature.status
```

are also disabled by default. For more info, you can check this [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) page.

Comment: In FF15 this only shows or hides the location bar, I can't edit it. Is there another config entry that allows editing? I can't seem to find one.